# Interface builder: Attribute Unavailable Identifier on Mac OS X versions prior to 10.7

Tags: macos, interface-builder

Development environment: OS X 10.7, Xcode 4.3.1
Deployment version: 10.6

Interface builder is giving me the warning: 'Attribute Unavailable Identifier on Mac OS X versions prior to 10.7'

How do I find out what it's complaining about?  Or, how do I fix this?  Obvious clicking around doesn't remove the warning.

Comment: I figured this out.  Never mind...

Comment: And what was the answer?  I have the same issue.

Comment: @trojanfoe: I wrote up the answer for you and anyone else who finds this question later.

Answer (score 1):

You gave something an identifier, but you're targeting an OS version from before the identifier attribute was introduced. Either raise your deployment target to 10.7 (or later), or take out the object's identifier.

Selecting the warning in the Issues Navigator should (IIRC) select the object that possesses the unsupported attribute.